# pg_terminate_backend does not work in loop

Tags: postgresql, loops

I do some thing like this

```
LOOP 
Exit when 1 = 2;
  SELECT pg_terminate_backend(procpid)
  FROM pg_stat_activity
   WHERE datname = 'wiki';
pg_sleep(10);
END LOOP;
```

But it only works for the first time.

the next time it's select the last time process and try to terminate them(they have been terminated) and throw Exception.

It's not going to stop but it isn't terminate new connections.

Why it doesn't find the new connections?

Tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_stat_activity` (and all other `pg_stat_xx`  views) show a snapshot of the time when the transaction started. As a function (including `do` blocks) is always executed in a transaction, your loop does not see any changes.

You need to call [`pg_stat_clear_snapshot()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#MONITORING-STATS-FUNCS-TABLE) to reset the current transaction's statistic snapshot, e.g. after the call to `pg_sleep()`.